# OpenGL Instanced rendering shape messed up

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering, opengl-4

I'm trying to build a voxel engine, and to do this I have to create hundreds of thousands of voxels, and I was hoping I could use instanced rendering. However, on rendering, the shape is completely disfigured, and not the expected cube shape:
[image: one voxel]

And with several voxels:
[image: several voxels]

This is what my code looks like:

chunk.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>

#include "voxel.hpp"

#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

using std::vector;
using glm::mat4;
using glm::vec3;


class Chunk {
    vec3 centerPoint;
    int voxelNum;
    int shaderProgram;
    unsigned int VBO, EBO, VAO;
    mat4 VP;
public:
    Chunk(vec3 center, float radius, int rinv);
    void setVP(mat4 vp);
    void draw();
};
```

chunk.cpp

```cpp
#include "chunk.hpp"

#include <stdlib.h>

Chunk::Chunk(vec3 centerPoint, float radius, int rinv) {
    vec3 endPoint(centerPoint.x - radius, centerPoint.y - radius, centerPoint.z - radius);
    
    float distVox = 2 * radius/rinv;
    
    voxelNum = pow(rinv, 3);
    
    mat4* modelMatrices = new mat4[voxelNum];
    srand(glfwGetTime()); // initialize random seed
    
    for (int z = 0; z < rinv; z++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < rinv; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < rinv; x++) {
                glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
                
                model = translate(model, vec3(endPoint.x + (x + 0.5) * distVox, endPoint.y + (y + 0.5) * distVox, endPoint.z + (z + 0.5) * distVox));
                model = scale(model, vec3(radius));
                
                int index = x + y * rinv + z * pow(rinv, 2);
                modelMatrices[index] = model;
            }
        }
    }
    
    const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
        "layout (location = 3) in mat4 aInstanceMatrix;\n"
        "uniform mat4 VP;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = VP * aInstanceMatrix * vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n\0";
    
    const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "uniform vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);\n"
        "}\n\0";

    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // link shaders
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    
    vec3 voxCenterPoint(0.0f);
    float voxRadius = 1.0f;
    
    vec3 maxV(voxCenterPoint.x + voxRadius, voxCenterPoint.y + voxRadius, voxCenterPoint.z + voxRadius);
    vec3 minV(voxCenterPoint.x - voxRadius, voxCenterPoint.y - voxRadius, voxCenterPoint.z - voxRadius);
    
    vec3 vertices[8] = {
        vec3(maxV.x, maxV.y, maxV.z),
        vec3(maxV.x, maxV.y, minV.z),
        vec3(maxV.x, minV.y, minV.z),
        vec3(maxV.x, minV.y, maxV.z),
        vec3(minV.x, minV.y, maxV.z),
        vec3(minV.x, maxV.y, maxV.z),
        vec3(minV.x, maxV.y, minV.z),
        vec3(minV.x, minV.y, minV.z),
    };
    
    unsigned int indices[36] = {
        0, 2, 1, // maxV.x
        0, 2, 3,

        2, 6, 1, // minV.z
        2, 6, 7,

        2, 4, 3, // minV.y
        2, 4, 7,

        4, 6, 5, // minV.x
        4, 6, 7,

        1, 5, 0, // maxV.y
        1, 5, 6,

        0, 4, 3, // maxV.z
        0, 4, 5,
    };
    
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // load data into vertex buffers
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//    // set the vertex attribute pointers
//    // vertex Positions
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vec3), (void*)0);
    
    // set attribute pointers for matrix (4 times vec4)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
    glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec4)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
    glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec4) * 2));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
    glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec4) * 3));

    glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(5, 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(6, 1);
    
    
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, voxelNum * sizeof(mat4), &modelMatrices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Chunk::setVP(mat4 vp) {
    VP = vp;
}

void Chunk::draw() {
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "VP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &VP[0][0]);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, voxelNum);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "chunk.hpp"

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;

//Global Variables
GLFWwindow* window;
const char* SCR_TITLE = "WORKINGPLANET";
const int SCR_WIDTH = 500, SCR_HEIGHT = 500;

float x_rot = 0.0f;
float y_rot = 0.0f;

float y_rot_clamp = 89.999f;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f; // time between current frame and last frame
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int button, int action, int mods);

vec3 X_AXIS = vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 Y_AXIS = vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

//Main Program
int main()
{
    //Constructor Code
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        cerr << "Error!!GLFW";
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    
    if(!(window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, SCR_TITLE, NULL, NULL)))
    {
        cerr << "Error!!GLFW window";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL context" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    
    Chunk chunk(vec3(0.0f), 0.5, 2);

    mat4 view = mat4(1.0);
    vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);
    view = lookAt(cameraPos, vec3(0,0,0), vec3(0,1,0));
    //Loop Events
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        // Tweak these values to change the sensitivity
        float scale_x = 7.0f / SCR_WIDTH;
        float scale_y = 7.0f / SCR_HEIGHT;
        float rotSpeed = 350.0f;
        float rot = scale_x * rotSpeed;

        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            rot = scale_y * rotSpeed;
            if (y_rot + rot > y_rot_clamp)
                rot = y_rot_clamp - y_rot;

            view = rotate(view, (float)radians(rot), X_AXIS);
            y_rot += rot;
        } if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            rot = scale_y * rotSpeed;
            if (y_rot - rot < -y_rot_clamp)
                rot = y_rot + y_rot_clamp;

            view = rotate(view, (float)radians(-rot), X_AXIS);
            y_rot -= rot;
        } if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            view = rotate(view, (float)radians(-rot), Y_AXIS);
            x_rot -= rot;
        } if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            view = rotate(view, (float)radians(rot), Y_AXIS);
            x_rot += rot;
        } if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_R) == GLFW_PRESS) {
            view = lookAt(cameraPos, vec3(0,0,0), vec3(0,1,0));
            x_rot = 0.0f;
            y_rot = 0.0f;
        }

        mat4 projection = perspective(radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        //Rendering
        chunk.setVP(projection * view);
        chunk.draw();
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}
```

At first I thought this could be an indices issue, but trying to modify them only revealed that vertices seemed to be out of order. Trying a vector changed nothing (as expected).

Trying to modify the modelMatrices also resulted in nothing of consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66618364/2327517), you used the geometry also as transformation matrices. This time, you use the transformation matrices also as geometry.

Here you fill `VBO` with the vertex data:

> ```
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
> ```

Now you set up your position pattribute to source the data from this VBO, so far, so good:

> ```
> glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vec3), (void*)0);
> ```

Now, you set up your instane attributes 3 to 7, to also source the vertex data from your VBO:

> ```
> // set attribute pointers for matrix (4 times vec4)
> glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
> glVertexAttribPointer(3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::mat4), (void*)0);
> [...]
> ```

This already doesn't make any sense, but it only gets worse:

> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, voxelNum * sizeof(mat4), &modelMatrices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

Now you have *completely* **overwritten** your geometry data with the transformation matrices, the actual geometry of your cube **is lost**. Your position attribute still points into `VBO`, so it will interpret the matrices as the geometry.

In the scheme you're using, you need *two* *distinct* VBOs, one for the geomerty data, and one for the *per-oinstance transformation matrices*. (You can of course also store both data in one VBO, but than you have to deal yourself with storing both parts without overwriting each other, and with supplying the correct offsets, so let's ignore that option here).

When I wrote (empahsis added by me now):

> You need to move the attribute setup **for the instanced attribute**
> out of `Voxel::generateElement()` and into `Chunk::Chunk()` so you can
> tell it to use that VBO as source for the model matrices.

I meant exactly that. You need to setup up the instanced attributes 3 to 7 - and **only** these - to source the model matrix VBO, and leave the position attribute to source from the geometry VBO where it initially was.